# How do i view the local database version in safari on the iphone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

I am trying to see the localDatabase version from my iPhone in safari but it is not displaying, according to the docs i am supposed to be able to do this:

```
var db = openDatabase('dbShortName', '', 'dbLongName', 1000);
alert(db.version);
```

and it should alert the current version number. It does not. It works in Chrome and safari for the desktop but not the iPhone. Does anybody have some idea why?

My next option is to store the version in a separate table, but I would prefer to use the built in system. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your iPhone, if you go to Settings and scroll down to Safari, there's a Databases button which shows you the current databases on the phone. Does the database you're trying to open definitely exist?

Comment: Yes the database does exist, just does not show the version number.